# How to prevent Host Header Injection in PHP and Apache

Tags: php, apache

I want my website to prevent host header injection, to achieve this I applied the following code in PHP.

```
$allowed_hosts = [
    "127.0.0.1",
    "localhost",
    "10.x.x.28"
];

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && !in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $allowed_hosts)) {
    http_response_code(403);
    die();
}

if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) && !in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $allowed_hosts)) {
    http_response_code(403);
    die();
}
```

When I check it using BurpSuite it works fine for http://localhost/mysite/  (with a trailing slash)
but when I access http://localhost/mysite (without a trailing slash) with manipulated host header above code does not make any effect.

Please suggest to me that if I have to configure the server or have to write code.

Comment: My guess is that your webserver does a quick redirect from `http://localhost/mysite` to `http://localhost/mysite/`.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your `.htaccess` file

```
DirectorySlash Off
SetHandler some-handler
```

I hope this will work.